# Google / Yandex translation API equivalent?

Tags: translation, google-translate

I'm working on a project where I have about 100 million characters into four languages. Google's translation API is no longer free and it seems that other API's have serious limitations that preclude my ability to use them.

I have evaluated Google, Yandex and Bing and none of them offer sufficient high bounds limits to make this work.  I'm completely drawing blanks here.

Are there any unrestricted translation services that are comparable to Google or Yandex that offer essentially an unrestricted translation service that is very high quality?

Answer (score 4):

I too researched a bit. Have you tried this? http://mymemory.translated.net/

Comment: Interesting find, but it has too low of an api limit.  But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though not direct to your question... here is some help setting up Yandex for the first time:

[Building the PrimeFaces Mobile Translation Demo with NetBeans and Yandex API](http://robertjliguori.blogspot.com/2016/09/building-primefaces-mobile-translation.html)